# Dynamic Display after adding Data to SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My main screen is a list of names queried from database ,which on click gives certain information about the name(Phone number,Hierarchy, mail id etc).I also have options to edit and add new contact(I have added buttons to do so ). Everything works fine , but , I cannot see the names immediately when I update the names into database. But when I rerun the application , I can see the changes . How do I display the names dynamically and ***efficiently***? 
One thing I can think is query the database again , onResume and display.But I don't feel it is efficient enough.
Also I could use startActivityforResult() but I cant arrange them in ascending order and I upload many contacts at a time.

CODE

```
    // Make a New Database
    DBContact info = new DBContact(this);
    info.open();
    String[] data = info.queryAll();
    info.close();
    // Display the names
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Contacts.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) in the docs. When you have added data to the database, call this to update the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LoaderManager to hook your database data with the Database adapter. It will give you two advantages -

1. It does not run on UI thread to fetch the data, hence no lag in display.
2. It will automatically refresh data if something is changed in the database.

More details here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using a CursorAdapter or a SimpleCursorAdapter, and use that directly in your view instead of wrapping the results of your query inside a array adapter.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

2 tasks you need to do:

1. Add data in the database
2. Check if data is inserted successfully, then add the same data in your Adapter. Don't forget to call **[notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)** after modifying data in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

as workaround try to restart loader in this way:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```